# moment.js - which one would be the correct output, considering that my timezone is GMT-3?

Tags: javascript, time, timezone, momentjs

For some reason, when I retrieve a previous saved date from the database and try to convert it to my local time, it differs from the current time.

This is my code:

```
// got accessToken from database
console.log(moment(accessToken.expiresAt).toDate());
console.log(moment().toDate());
```

The output is:

```
Fri Aug 25 2017 20:47:51 GMT-0300 (BRT)
Fri Aug 25 2017 17:47:51 GMT-0300 (BRT)
```

Considering that my current local time is 25/Aug/2017 17:47:51 and that the accessToken.expiresAt was saved in the same request (at the same time), which one would be the correct output?

And if someone have any idea of why my stored time (stored as timestamp in mysql) is differing from the current time, please lead me to a direction.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What shows `console.log(accessToken.expiresAt)`?

Comment: My guess is your input is UTC-based but is unspecified as such.  Without seeing your exact input (`accessToken.expiresAt`), it's impossible to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moment.js probably assumed that the access token time you saved was in UTC - try this:

```
console.log( moment( accessToken.expiresAt ).utc().toDate() );
```

You can check the difference between your local timezone and UTC by entering your timestamp in a date converter such as http://www.convertunixdate.com - to get your timestamp, execute this:

```
moment( accessToken.expiresAt ).unix()
```